# qgis-web-client Not rendering label fonts

Tags: qgis, qgis-web-client

My install of qgis-web-client is not rendering label fonts, each character appears as a black box / square.

See screenshot:

[image]

Tested in FF & Chrome, have tried changing from the MS system font to Aerial with no change.